# What does "probabilistic algorithm with random tape" mean?

Tags: cryptography, digital-signature, random

I am new to the study of cryptography, and when reading papers they often mention that "probabilistic algorithm G with random tape w ...". What does it mean by "random tape w"? I mean why it does is not just refer to probabilistic algorithm G?

Comment: Could you provide an example, maybe a link to such a paper? I have no idea what you're talking about (maybe someone else does, but a link might give me the context I need).

Comment: I did a google search and got Wiki as a top hit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_Turing_machine

Comment: [link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s001450010003), in Definition 1 (refer to "The key generation algorithm")

Comment: that is the case, my understanding is : one of the definition of Probabilistic Turing Machine is  "A type of nondeterministic TM where each nondeterministic step is called a coin-flip step and has two legal next moves" and  random tape is covered randomly (and independently)  with 0’s and 1’s, to determines which next moves should go.
Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

When computer science papers speak about tape, it usually concerns some form of [Turing machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine). A Turing machine is a fictional machine which can read and write binary values from positions on an infinite string of tape.

However, if this is the case the paper would definitely mention this or provide certain properties of the machine.